# What is the big O notation complexity of an algorithm with T(N) = 16N+8N^2+N^2log(n)+6NK+5N^2K-5NK^2

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I want to find the big O notation complexity of an algorithm with

```
T(N) = 16N+8N^2+N^2log(N)+6NK+5N^2K-5NK^2
```

Note that `K,N` are positive integers with `K<=N`

What would that be?

UPDATE
`K,N` are both inputs of the algorithm.

Comment: I am asking about the big O notation of this time complexity.

Comment: The answer is O(N^3) from the `5N^2K` term.

Comment: Notice the -5NK^2 term. Could that do something different to the big O because of the minus?

Comment: rule of thumb: lower-order terms are asymptotically negligible -- so neglect them. @jofel -- you are of course correct -- why not write it up as an answer?

Comment: I thought K is a constant, in which case that's an incorrect answer.

Comment: Κ and N are both input of the algorithm. Sorry for not mentioning that. I will add it to the question.

Comment: Then it's really `T(N,K)`.

Comment: @JohnColeman I did not write it down, because the chance was high, that someone will downvote it (and in fact it was downvoted, nobody knows why - therefore: do not answer downvoted questions).

Comment: @jofel I guess that is the risk when you reply to some questions. I upvoted your answer. Not all questions need long answers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `O(N^3)` from the `5N^2K` term.

Here the reason for the answer:

- `16N` is `O(N)`
- `8N^2` is `O(N^2)`
- `N^2 log(N)` is `O(N^2 Log(N))`
- `6NK` is `O(N^2)` as `K` is `O(N)`
- `5N^2K` is `O(N^3)` (same reason for `K`)
- `-5NK^2` is also `O(N^3)` as `K` could be negative and
  does not cancel always the previous `5N^2K` since `K<=N`.

The highest order is `O(N^3`) which is therefore answer.

If `T` would be function of both `N` and `K` (e.g. `T(N,K)`), and `K` is not `O(N)`, the answer is `O(N^2 K)` if `K<N`
and `O(N^2 log(N))` for `N==K`.

Comment: What if K is small? And what if K==N?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath added this case.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but someone might have due to you not explaining _why_ those are the answers.

Comment: @VincentSavard I extended the answer, so this should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If N and K are both inputs, then big O will be a function of both the inputs.

1. 16N has O(N)
2. 8N^2 hass O(N^2)
3. N^2.log(N) has O(N^2 log(N))
4. 6NK has O(NK)
5. 5N^2K has O((N^2)*K)
6. 5NK^2 has O((N)*K^2)

As its given that K<=N, for all values of K and N, the complexity will be O((N^2)*K), for this being the highest term in asymptotic terms among rest of all.
However for a special case like N=K, it can be written as O(N^3) or O(K^3).